# ruby & nlp: how to remove stop words and non-words (e.g. link, emoji) and count uniq words?

Tags: ruby, nlp

Some sample data

`NEW LISTING: @AaveAave AAVE ($LEND) will SOON be listed on @OKEx! Quiz &amp; Net Buy  up to 3,000 $LEND: ▶️ Follow us + @AaveAave ▶️ Join Quiz: https://t.co/{.....} ▶️ RT answer &amp; @OKEx #OKExDeFi #OKExAave ▶️ Deposit + Net Buying rebate Listing details: https://t.co/{.....} hhttps://t.co/{.....}`

`100,000,000 #USDT (100,568,399 USD) transferred from Tether Treasury to #Binance Tx: https://t.co/{.....}`

What I plan to do

- remove all stop words
- remove all non-words (link and emoji)
- count word number and unique word number

My question: I know how to do this in R (using `tidytext`), but what is the best practice doing the above in Ruby? I searached around but didn't know any popular related gems.

Thanks to your help

---

If it's `tidytext`, the above can be pretty much done as shown below

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you googled, but I found lots of suggestions for language processing: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-natural-language-ruby/index.html https://github.com/dbalatero/lingua https://github.com/yohasebe/engtagger https://github.com/diasks2/chat_correct https://github.com/rossmeissl/verbs

Comment: @TomLord for example, `lingua` is not maintained anymore and not at the same level as `tidytext` in R.

Comment: Is there a specific feature/capability that's missing/broken? It may well be the case that there's no library in ruby with the same capability as `tidytext`, but that may not mean you can't solve your specific problem in ruby. Additionally, as I suggested above, it may be a viable alternative to call an API in ruby so that the actual computation is performed in another language / via a third party.

Comment: Please define "stop words" and "link". Is a "word" a string of word characters that is neither preceded nor followed by a word character, a string of non-whitespace characters that is neither preceded nor followed by a non-whitespace character, or something else? When you give an example it's always helpful to show the desired result. I suggest you edit the question rather than elaborate in comments.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like you’ve tried nothing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I feel it's not that hard? as it's pretty standard in `tidytext` as I updated in the question.

Comment: If you are willing to limit your audience to Rubyists who are familiar with tidytext I expect you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Take an Incremental Approach to Sanitizing Your Input

Your question is non-trivial because you haven't really defined "[stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words)" or "non-words" in a programmatic way, and there's no universal list of such. There isn't even a 100% accurate way to detect all valid [web URIs](https://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls), much less URIs using other schemes, although there are some "good enough and better than most" approaches.

However, as a basic starting point for rolling your own:

```
stop_words = /\b(a|an|the|and|or)\b/
non_words  = /\s+(#\p{ASCII}|https?:|@).*?\s+/

str = <<~'EOF'
  NEW LISTING: @AaveAave AAVE ($LEND) will SOON be listed on @OKEx! Quiz &amp; Net Buy  up to 3,000 $LEND: ▶️ Follow us + @AaveAave ▶️ Join Quiz: https://t.co/{.....} ▶️ RT answer &amp; @OKEx #OKExDeFi #OKExAave ▶️ Deposit + Net Buying rebate Listing details: https://t.co/{.....} hhttps://t.co/{.....}

            100,000,000 #USDT (100,568,399 USD) transferred from Tether Treasury to #Binance Tx: https://t.co/{.....} 
EOF

str.gsub! stop_words, ""
str.gsub! non_words, ""
str.gsub! /[[:^ascii:]]/, ""
str.strip!
str.squeeze!

p "Chars: #{str.length}"
#=> "Chars: 246"

p "Words: #{str.split.uniq.count}"
#=> "Words: 35"
```

There's still some further cleanup you'd need to do because your input is not standardized. Still, this should provide you a good starting point and a reasonable approach to finding your own "good enough" solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For stop words they are from `tidytext` dataset, and for non-words let's just remove the links. I updated in the questions to give you a simple example. And now I think I should follow your approach, just use regex to do this.